# How to use Date Formatter to get from 00:00:00 (through 23:00:00) to 1 - 12 am/pm format?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get from 24 hrs like 5:00:00 to 5 am, but I'm having difficulty understanding how.

I have tried a few similar things, but eventually got to this:

```
let date: String = "5:00:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
let theDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
myDateText.text = dateFormatter.string(from: theDate) // myDateText is a UILabel
```

I expected it to be 5 am but received an error that theDate is nil. I'm a newbie, so I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You're assigning the result of the first parsing to `theDate`, but using `myDate` when you try to format it :/. Also, AFAIK `HH` is for 24 hour time (ie `17` == `5 pm`) and `hh` is for 12 hour time

Comment: marked as  **Typo mistake**   theDate should be at myDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HH** is stand for 24 hours and **hh** is stand for 12 hours.

```
let date: String = "15:00:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let theDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: theDate!))
```

Output is `03:00 PM`